# Flutter project build failed with Kotlin Gradle plugin version error

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

I am facing an error while building my Flutter project. The error message is as follows:

````
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20

 * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org```
````

I am using the location: 4.4.0 package in my pubspec.yaml file. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What is kotlin version of your project?

Comment: ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'

Comment: Can you please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693595/flutter-the-android-gradle-plugin-supports-only-kotlin-gradle-plugin-version-1

Answer (score 0):

Following [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707388/9494140) i did the following:

```
dependencies {         
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1' // I changed this to 7.2.1 
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"     
}
```